# initWithDictionary

Tags: cocoa, class

I have the problem that I can't get the Data from one of my classes to the other...

To do this I created this method in the class I am initializing (angebotPage):

```
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    dict = [dictionary retain];
}

    return self;
}
```

The call from the other class looks like this:

```
angebotPage *page;
angebotPDF = [[PDFDocument alloc] init];
page = [[angebotPage alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];
```

The Error I get is EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the line where I do:

```
dict = [dictionary retain];
```

But why? I need to retain it cause I will use it for the next program steps.. But without retaining I can't use it (EXC_BAD_ACCESS comes elsewhere...)

Comment: How do you allocate your `dictionary` object in the following code? `page = [[angebotPage alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];`

Comment: The dictionary is just filled with test data:

dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            @"/opt/picture.png", @"Luca", 
            @"/home/nico/birthday.png", @"Birthday Photo", 
            @"/home/nico/birthday.png", @"Birthday Image", 
            @"/home/marghe/pic.jpg", @"My Sister", nil];


Sorry.. I am a noob ;) but I really wanna sold this problem!

Comment: And where do you do this? Remember that [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:ids ..., nil]; returns an autoreleased NSDictionary to you. If I was you I would do something like this instead: `NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectAndKeys:ids ..., nil];` and then release it again after you have given it to your `page = [[angebotPage alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];`. Like this: `[dictionary release];`

Comment: The next problem occurred: Normally you would get an dictionary object with the key: `[dict objectForKey:@"nodesign"]` but how does it work when I have NSMutableArray's in my Dictionary, I can't find anything in google :(

Comment: @chr1s9r: That's a separate question, which you should ask separately, not as a comment on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a property for dict instead.

```
@property (retain) NSDictionary *dict;
```

And then assign the dictionary with `self.dict = dictionary.` This is assuming all the objects in dictionary are correctly retained in the first place. Try with an empty dictionary if in doubt.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of the dictionary having been over-released before `initWithDictionary:` tried to retain it. You would still be trying to retain a dead object.